# Function JavaScript maparea

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image with a map and located an area like this:

```
<img src="Stockwerk_Namen_Dosen_Belegung_2012_07_03.ai2.svg" width="1202" height="294" alt="Plan" usemap="#planmap">

<map name="#planmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="9,7,60,70" alt="1.4.08" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank">
<area shape="rect" coords="8,83,61,148" alt="1.4.07"
onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank">
</map>
.
.
.
<script...>
    function myFunction() {
    //Here is my Problem
    }

`
</script...
```

How can I put the alt-Text into the Function?

Comment: Do you want to pass 'alt' as an argument to myFunction?

Comment: The text that is in alt so in this case "1.4.07".

Comment: see Quentin's answer: use `this.getAttribute('alt')` inside `myFunction`.

Comment: @TarunDugar — No. Don't use that inside `myFunction`. My answer said the `onclick` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an event handler function (like `onclick`), `this` will refer to the element that the event fired upon (i.e. the `<area>`). You can use that with `getAttribute`.

Comment: So something like: `<area onclick="myFunction(this.alt)">`?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat — Yes.

Comment: ´window.alert(this.getAttribute('alt'));´ i wrote this into 'myFunction()' and got an Refference Error

Comment: @BesnikRamadani — I can't see any reason that would give you a reference error. None of the identifiers in that chuck of code should ever be undeclared in a browser JS environment. Try providing a [MCVE] and quoting the complete error message.

Comment: u put it into the question

Comment: Your update (a) Doesn't include the error message and (b) Doesn't include the code I said you should use.

Comment: The Error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: alt is not definedmyFunction @ testdoc.html:29onclick @ testdoc.html:12`

I included your code in myFunction but it didn't worked for me

Comment: @BesnikRamadani — You still haven't shown us the code that is generating that error (also "inside myFunction" is not where I said you should use it, and it isn't where Whothehellisthat put it in their comment)

Comment: just a basic window alert

`function myFunction() {

window.alert(this.getAttribute(alt));
}`

Comment: @BesnikRamadani — (a) I said put it in the `onclick` function not the `myFunction` function. (b) You haven't defined an `alt` variable, `getAttribute` expects the name of the attribute to be passed as a **string**. You forgot the quote marks.